# Search in complex documents in mongo db

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume i have the following document in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e36c34eb2832aa68b39b26"),
    "ap_domain" : "root",
    "average_down" : 123,
    "average_up" : 234,
    "peak_down" : 123,
    "peak_up" : 456,
    "ssid_shaper_list" :
    {
        "SSID1" : {
            "ssid_domain" : "root",
                "peak_up" : 456,
                "peak_down" : 456
        },
        "SSID2" : {
            "ssid_domain" : "root",
                "average_up" : 567,
                "average_down" : 567,
                "peak_up" : 456,
                "peak_down" : 456
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check that `SSID2` exists in this document. Here I have 3 keys:

```
1. ap_domain = root
2. ssid_shaper_list = SSID2 and in it:
3. ssid_domain = root
```

How should i compose my search criteria in java using BasicDBObject to check that needed SSIDi exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query contains all your search conditions:

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("ap_domain", "root").append("ssid_shaper_list.SSID2.ssid_domain", "root");
```

You don't need to check if `SSID2` exists in `ssid_shaper_list` as the second part of the query implicitly does that.

The following query can be used to fetch documents that have `SSID2` object in the `ssid_shaper_list` array.

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("ssid_shaper_list.SSID2", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But i have to consider the 'ssid_domain' as the 3rd search param..

Comment: @user1053031: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The match of ssid_domain = root already implies that SSID2 is present. Thus, you have:

```
Filters.and(
    Filters.eq("ap_domain", "root"),
    Filters.eq("ssid_shaper_list.SSID2.ssid_domain", "root"));
```

Use that filter in the MongoCollection.find() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify your search criteria by combining 2. and 3. so your query would look like:

`{ap_domain: 'root', 'ssid_shaper_list.SSID2.ssid_domain': 'root'}`

The second key uses dot notation to specify embedded documents, more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#query-on-embedded-documents)

Depending upon your mongo driver version you may want to use [QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html) (pre 3.0) which will return a [Basic]DBObject, or [Filters](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) (3.0+) which will give you Bson that can still be used the same way for queries and looks cleaner.